# Pandas series from dictionary

Tags: pandas

Here's a fragment of my data.
I would like to convert this dictionary into a series with a multiindex. This seems aspect seems to work, however all values in the series are NaN?

```
d = {(datetime.date(2017, 10, 19), 1026972): 24.91, (datetime.date(2017, 10, 19), 1026973): 10.68, (datetime.date(2017, 10, 19), 1026974): 654.7}
```

I have tried `pd.Series(d)`

Any hints for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use multi index from tuples and set it as index, then pass the dict values to series.

```
s = pd.Series(list(d.values()),index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys()))
```

Output :

```
2017-10-19  1026974    654.70
            1026973     10.68
            1026972     24.91
dtype: float64
```

Comment: And it is interesting your MultiIndex is not sorted, hmmm, no idea why

Comment: Its maybe because ordering of dict in python 3.5

Comment: I'm digging the new dp. Also, dicts in python3.5 aren't ordered (the ordering starts from 3.6).

Answer (score 2):

I think there is problem in `Series` constructor are `date`s convert to `datetime`s and then values are not matched with `python date`s - get `NaN`s.

```
s = pd.Series(d)
print (s.index.get_level_values(0))
DatetimeIndex(['2017-10-19', '2017-10-19', '2017-10-19'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Solution is convert `datetime`s to `timestamp`s or create `Series` separately like in [Bharath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47012733/2901002) answer:

```
d = {(pd.Timestamp(k[0]), k[1]):v for k, v in d.items()}

print (d)
{(Timestamp('2017-10-19 00:00:00'), 1026973): 10.68, 
 (Timestamp('2017-10-19 00:00:00'), 1026974): 654.7, 
 (Timestamp('2017-10-19 00:00:00'), 1026972): 24.91}

s = pd.Series(d)
print (s)

2017-10-19  1026972     24.91
            1026973     10.68
            1026974    654.70
dtype: float64
```